# How to make this in C?

Tags: c

I'm with the following problem: the users inputs a valid number and it draws all the numbers it saves into the array in a triangle format, like this:

```
    O 
   OOO 
  OOOOO 
 OOOOOOO
```

But when I try making this with the following code, I can't find a logic to make it, i've tried adding spaces for each lines, but it doesn't help.

Actual output for num = 4:

```
   O O O O O O O
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you post the actual output your program produces, please?

Comment: The value of x is never set.

Comment: What is there now?

Comment: Added the output to the program.

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing in your program?

Comment: Also, x is being set here ```x = num;```

Comment: For example, what are the variables `i, j, k, x` intend to represent?

Comment: Yes but `x` is used in the comparison `num < x` before its value is set. Also, there are two variables `x`, one shadowing the another.

Comment: Rolled back vandalized question:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overcomplicating a very simple task:

```
void draw(unsigned lines, char ch)
{
    for(unsigned line = 1; line <= lines; line++)
    {
        for(unsigned space = 0; space < lines - line; space++) printf(" ");
        for(unsigned letter = 0; letter < (line -1) * 2 + 1 ; letter++) printf("%c", ch);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    draw(7,'0');
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fPYbcb8eW

```
      0
     000
    00000
   0000000
  000000000
 00000000000
0000000000000
```

Comment: o.O It's muck more simpler! Thanks a lot for you time!

Comment: Your use of `unsigned variableName` here seems very unorthodox.  What is the motivation for not simply using an `int`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey can the number of rows be negative? Use the type which fits the job.

Comment: You don't use the full range of the datatype you chose either, but you used it anyway.   
  Using `unsigned` (especially without a declaring type) causes the programmer who has to read your code a moment of confusion and time spent answering the question, "Why did he do it that way?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I actually ask myself "Why did he do it that way?" when I see a parameter meant to only take positive values but still has `int` type. Not only does it (to me at least) indicate that a negative value is okay to pass, but if the function assumes that the value is positive and a neg value is passed then it can cause bugs and issues. Also if you mean `unsigned` as opposed to `unsigned int` by _(especially without a declaring type)_ then I think that's pretty common, but I can't say for sure about that. Though I suppose `unsigned` vs `unsigned int` can only be a subjective opinion.

Comment: C allows your "unsigned" to accept negative values, making it as unsafe as `int`.  https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/GlisteningAgedPatterns#main.c.  If you really want to do this right, you will write code that validates the input parameters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey type of parameters never makes code safe. But having `unsigned` type you show other programmers what your intentions are (you do not want negative numbers).  It is the caller responsibility to pass the correct value. Using `unsigned` instead `unsigned int` is the same common as using `long` instead of `long int`